# domain name converts to IP in browser bar, using apache webserver

Tags: apache, dns, ip

I'm trying to configure my new domain name to my home server running apache. I've set up httpd.conf in apache, so that I can access my website from the domain name on the web, the problem is that when I go to the domain name, the browser address changes to my server IP. The httpd.conf stuff I've set is:

```
#VIRTUAL DocumentRoot
#VIRTUAL ServerName
#VIRTUAL ServerAdmin

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin ***
DocumentRoot "***"
ServerName ***
</VirtualHost>
```

On the domain side, I have an HTTP redirect to my server public IP. Can someone point me on the direction of what is supposed to be configured differently, thanks.

Comment: this is offtopic. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

turns out I needed to find and edit the 'A Record' for my domain name provider, hidden away in advanced settings...changing from the domain provider IP to my server IP